# Помогите с ошибкой, "Не удалось привести тип объекта "System.DataTime" к типу "System.String"

Tags: c#

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
    MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(connStr);
                    conn.Open();



                        string sql = $"select subscribe from dle_users where email = '{textBoxUserEmail.Text}' and password = '{sspass}' ";
                        MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(sql, conn);
                        command.Prepare();
                        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (textBoxUserEmail.Text == (string)command.ExecuteScalar())
                    {
                        DateTime d1;
                        try
                        {
                            string date = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString();
                            var client = new TcpClient("time.nist.gov", 13);
                            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(client.GetStream()))
                            {
                                var response = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
                                var utcDateTimeString = response.Substring(7, 17);
                                d1 = DateTime.ParseExact(utcDateTimeString, "yy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
                            }

                            DateTime d2 = Convert.ToDateTime(date);
                            TimeSpan time = d2 - d1;

                            int days = time.Days;

                            if (days > 0)
                            {
                                passlIsPass = true;
                                if (conn != null && conn.State != ConnectionState.Closed)
                                    conn.Close();
                            }
                            if (days < 0)
                            {
                                DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Продлите подписку !", "Внимание", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                            }

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Ошибка", "Внимание", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

                        }
                    }


                    else
                    {
                        passlIsPass = false;
                        DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("Логин или пароль введен неверно", "Внимание", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
                    }
```

Comment: @Bulson  добавил скрин

Comment: @Bulson это удалить ?

Comment: @Bulson  string date = command.ExecuteScalar().ToString(); заменить на это string date = (string)command.ExecuteScalar()

Comment: @Bulson я сделал как вы сказали но теперь у меня всегда равно ложь и говорит что логин и пароль неверны, хотя до этого без проверки даты все работало ! if (textBoxUserEmail.Text == command.ExecuteScalar().ToString())

Comment: Я писал как исправить ошибку в строке, в которой она возникает. А не логику выполнения вашего кода. Чуете разницу?

Comment: @Bulson да но получается так что переменная становится исковерканной, если бы вы написали правильно, то мне не писало бы - что логин и пароль неверны и далее продолжилось бы действие !

Comment: @АндрюхаРейз, очевидно, что в твоем случае ExecuteScalar возвращает дату, странно пытаться сравнивать ее со строкой.

Comment: какое значение находится в `textBoxUserEmail.Text`? что за поле `subscribe` в таблице `dle_users`?